# Why does Spring data throw SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException when saving an entity with a relation to itself?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

So im developing a project in which i have an entity that holds a relation to itself. Now for some reason when i try to save an entity (made in a react app sent through rest) it throws:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`post`.`post_sections`, CONSTRAINT `FKdg8t1aa12xxpo5bwa6ef634x2` FOREIGN KEY (`sections_id`) REFERENCES `sections` (`id`))
```

Now this is my entity:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = SQL.SECTION_TABLE)
@ToString(doNotUseGetters = true)
@Entity(name = SQL.SECTION_ENTITY)
@EqualsAndHashCode(doNotUseGetters = true)
public class SectionDAO implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "uuid2", strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "BINARY(16)", unique = true)
    @GenericGenerator(name = "uuid2", strategy = "org.hibernate.id.UUIDGenerator")
    private UUID id;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<SectionDAO> children = new HashSet<>();

    @ToString.Exclude
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private SectionDAO parent;

    @ToString.Exclude
    @ElementCollection
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    private List<Translation> localizations;
}
```

All the others work, because i have the spring data hibernate logs and it only blows up when inserting the so called "children". Is there any reason i don't see here to justify it not working?

Comment: you need to make sure you insert the children in the same transaction as and only after you already inserted the parent, otherwise it won't find the foreign key id pointing to the parent

Comment: well im using spring data, i insert through the "save" method and the children are in the parent. I also have my method annotated @Transactional. What else can i do to ensure that?